# html template wont render in python django

Tags: python, django

I know this is a very noob question but need help with this when I try to render my product template it returns with this error , the first two pages were rendered correctly such as  about , **home** and **contact** but when I tried to add another app for my **products** page it wouldnt load.

```
#THE ERROR
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/%7B%25%20url%20'products'%7D
Using the URLconf defined in trydjango.urls, Django tried these URL 
patterns, in this order:
1. ^admin/
2. ^$ [name='home']
3. ^about/$ [name='about']
4. ^products/$ [name='products']
5. ^contact/$ [name='contact']
6. ^accounts/
7.^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
8.^static\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, {% url 'products'}, did not match any of these.

#This is the structure
src
>> contact
>> products
   >> migrations
   >> templates
      >> products.html 
>> profiles
>> migrations
>> templates
   >> about.html
   >> base.html
   >> home.html
   >> navbar.html

#from the products app this is the views.py

def products(request):
   context = {}
   template = 'products.html'
   return render(request, template,context)

#This is the config for urls


from profiles import views as profiles_views
from contact import views as contact_views
from products import views as products_views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^$', profiles_views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^about/$', profiles_views.about, name='about'),
url(r'^products/$', products_views.products, name='products'),
url(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact, name='contact'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

]

#and this is where I called it in navbar
<li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{%url'products'}">Products</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also appear to me missing the closing '%' on the link template tag.
It should be

```
<a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{% url 'products' %}">Products</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't name the urls if it have a include, to do that go to the urls and add:

```
app_name='products'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', your_view.path, name='home'),

]
```

and the refer it to:

```
{% url 'products:home' %}
```